# Thoroughly conveying my protagonist's thoughts and emotions

Tags: creative-writing, horror

I'm currently writing a story in which our protagonist is trapped in a labyrinth of sorts. The twist here is that she is the monster within this maze yet she does not realize it as she has no memory of any recent events and simply woke up there. Over the course of this short story, she learns of what she is and slowly regains her memories. But just as quickly as she regains her memories, they begin to fade as she is slowly devolving into a mindless beast. **What would you say is the best way to approach my protagonist's thoughts and emotions throughout this?**

Comment: What point of view are you using? First person, tight third person, omniscient third person, ...? That seems likely to have a significant impact on the choices available to you, and certainly on which would be good or bad for what you're trying to convey.

Comment: I'm using first person

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This question is right on the edge of "what to write," which is off-topic for us — asking us to help you with *your particular story* — because it is so specific. Can you make this a bit broader? It's a good question about technique and I would prefer not to close it for being too localized.

Comment: Welcome Baron360.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  Glad you found us.  It sounds like a really interesting story but I'm in agreement with @LaurenIpsum that, in its current form, it's too much like a "tell me what to write" question.  Can you edit it a bit so it's the answers are those that might help other writers with similar situations?

Answer (score 1):

You can play about with consciousness so that she has flashbacks into actions performed in an unconscious state. That would allow her to have a sense of herself that is at variance with what her own mind reveals about her past actions; as if she's seeing them for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think once you settle on how this transformation takes place that you’ll understand how to relate it in your story.  Is the transformation outward to inward — they take on appearance of monster and slowly their mind and values are monstery?  Or do they wrestle with in inner transformation the takes their mind first and then transforms the body?

And is it continuous?  Or can they focus on the mission, or remember their true love and gain respite or ground from the transformation?

Once you have that arc of transformation solidly understood, then you’ll see how to represent it in terms of the characters dialog, interior thoughts, emotions and actions